# Scrapy IdentationError: expected an idented block

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Trust you are doing well. Please I need your help, I´m obtaining this error but I don´t know why:

```
    File "C:\Users\Luis\Amazon\mercado\spiders\spider.py", line 14
yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_item)
    ^IndentationError: expected an indented block

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urllib
from mercado.items import MercadoItem


class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercado'
    item_count = 0
    allowed_domain = ['https://www.amazon.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1 535314254']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_item)

        for i in range(2,400):
            yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page="+str(i)+"&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()

        #info de producto
        ml_item['articulo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="productTitle"])').extract()
        ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"])').extract()
        self.item_count += 1
        yield ml_item
```

Do you know why?
I' ve added the code here to do it easily.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Provide the code block to investigate the issue completely.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your support I´ve added the code at the main message.

Comment: Seems you have missed indentation in def start_requests(self):. Those functions are supposed to be inside the class but they are not.

Comment: Really thank you! Please could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: I have made the edit in your question itself. use the code in your question,

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urllib
from mercado.items import MercadoItem


class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercado'
    item_count = 0
    allowed_domain = ['https://www.amazon.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1 535314254']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_item)

        for i in range(2,400):
            yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page="+str(i)+"&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_item)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()

        #info de producto
        ml_item['articulo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="productTitle"])').extract()
        ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"])').extract()
        self.item_count += 1
        yield ml_item
```

**UPDATE** But right now you have code (not optimal) to get pagination and parse details page. You need to add code to parse each pagination page and get detail link for each item:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page=1&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_search)

    for i in range(2,400):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.amazon.es/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1951051031%2Cn%3A2424922031%2Ck%3Afebi&page="+str(i)+"&keywords=febi&ie=UTF8&qid=1535314254",self.parse_search)

def parse_search(self, response):

    for item_link in response.xpath('//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]//a[contains(@class, "s-access-detail-page")]/@href').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(item_link, self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    ml_item = MercadoItem()

    #info de producto
    ml_item['articulo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="productTitle"])').extract()
    ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"])').extract()
    self.item_count += 1
    yield ml_item
```

Comment: Awesome!! Is working! Thank you  very much! The problem that I´ve right now is that I´m only onbtaining two results per page from 24 possible, do you know why?